# How to know which package installs a given command?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I see that llvm-objdump-9 instead of llvm-objdump are installed. What is the command to figure out which package installs it? How to remove the suffix -9? Thanks.

EDIT: Please reopen the post. The second question is not answered.

To get llvm-objdump in my `$PATH`, do I need to add `/usr/lib/llvm-9/bin` in my `$PATH`?

```
$ dpkg -S llvm-objdump
llvm-9: /usr/share/man/man1/llvm-objdump-9.1.gz
llvm-9: /usr/lib/llvm-9/bin/llvm-objdump
llvm-9: /usr/bin/llvm-objdump-9
```

Comment: Please ask a new question about your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a file:

```
$ sudo apt install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file search llvm-objdump
```

That searches the contents of the package archive, so works for all packages whether they are installed or not.

If you know the package is already installed:

```
$ dpkg -S  llvm-objdump
```